# getting an undefined value in test case but not in production

Tags: javascript, angular6

When this function is called by my test case, I see that the value of `index` is `undefined`.

```
delete thumbnail  clicked with context  {thumbnailContext: ThumbnailContext}thumbnailContext: ThumbnailContext {divId: "thumbnail-1", imgId: "img-1", closeId: "close-button-1", imgSrc: "data:image/png;base64,Zm9vMQ==", index: 0, …}__proto__: Object
context.js:1972 deleting index  undefined
```

But the trace just before that in the same function shows that the value is actually 0!

The function in question is

```
  deleteThumbnail(thumbnailContext:ThumbnailContext){

    console.log("delete thumbnail  clicked with context ",thumbnailContext); //the print of this shows index is 0
    let wasConfirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the attachment?");
    if(wasConfirmed) {


      console.log("deleting index ", thumbnailContext.index); //and then this becomes undefined!!
      this.thumbnailContainerRef.remove(thumbnailContext.index);

      return false; /*returning false cancels the click and thus cancels further navigation and prevents the browser from going to the page specified (in this case #).*/
    }
  }
```

The code run shows the correct prints if run outside the test environment though (i.e. in dev mode)

The following is the test case. It tests that a user can delete a thumbnail of a view. The thumbnail is created using `Angular''s`ViewContainerRef`.

```
  fit('should delete image if user deletes a thumbnail', (done) => {
    let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;

    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(0);
    let imageThumbnailDiv = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-1"));
    let imageThumbnailImg = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-1'));
    let imageThumbnailClose = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-1'));


    expect(imageThumbnailDiv).toBeFalsy();
    expect(imageThumbnailImg).toBeFalsy();
    expect(imageThumbnailClose).toBeFalsy();
    let fileSelectControl = (fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#question-file-upload"))).nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    let file1 = new File(["foo1"], "foo1.txt",{type: "image/png"});
    let reader = newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect(fileSelectControl,[file1]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("in timeout");

      fixture.detectChanges();//without this, the view will not be updated with model
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(1);
      let imageThumbnailDiv2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-1"));
      let imageThumbnailImg2= fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-1'));
      let imageThumbnailClose2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-1'));

      expect(imageThumbnailDiv2).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailImg2).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailClose2).toBeTruthy();

      let thumbnailViewRef:EmbeddedViewRef<ThumbnailContext> = newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.get(0) as EmbeddedViewRef<ThumbnailContext>;
      newPracticeQuestionComponent.deleteThumbnail(thumbnailViewRef.context);
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(0);

      let imageThumbnailDiv3 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-1"));
      let imageThumbnailImg3 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-1'));
      let imageThumbnailClose3 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-1'));


      expect(imageThumbnailDiv3).toBeFalsy();
      expect(imageThumbnailImg3).toBeFalsy();
      expect(imageThumbnailClose3).toBeFalsy();

      done();//without done, jasmine will finish this test spec without checking the assertions in the timeout
    }, 2000);


  });
```

The test case passes. However, I have another test case which is showing the same behavior but it hangs. the difference between that and this test case is the other one deletes multiple thumbnails.

Comment: from console log it seems thumbnailContext.thumbnailContext.index, can you share complete thumbnailContext log

Comment: thanks. You have pointed me in the right direction. If i change to argument type of `deleteThumbnail` to `any` and do `thumbnailContext.thumbnailContext.index` then I get the correct index. Happy to accept your answer.

Comment: posted my comment as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use thumbnailContext.thumbnailContext.index to get index value

Comment: i am wondering why the value of `thumbnailContext` which is `new ThumbnailContext` accessible via name `thumbnailContext`. I might still have not understood the naming convention to be honest.

Comment: I have created this new question regarding my doubt. Can you please take a look if you know `Angular`? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57938593/how-data-binding-works-between-ng-template-and-the-context-passed-to-the-templat