# how data binding works between ng-template and the context passed to the template using CreateEmbeddedView

Tags: angular6

I have this template.

```
<ng-template #thumbnailTemplate let-context="thumbnailContext"> 

  <div id="{{context.divId}}">
    <img id="{{context.imgId}}" src="{{context.imgSrc}}"> 
    <a href="#" id="{{context.closeId}}" (click)="this.deleteThumbnail(context)"></a> 
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

The following code create a view using the above template

```
  thumbnailTemplateViewRef = this.thumbnailContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.thumbnailTemplateRef,
      {thumbnailContext: new ThumbnailContext(divId, 
        imgId,
        closeId,
        imageString,this.thumbnailContainerRef.length,null)});
```

and when `deleteThumbnail` is called and the context is passed to it, I am accessing the index property as follows

`let index = thumbnailContext.thumbnailContext.index;`

```
  deleteThumbnail(thumbnailContext:any){
    console.log("delete thumbnail  clicked with context ",JSON.stringify(thumbnailContext));
    let index = thumbnailContext.thumbnailContext.index; //note that thumbnailContext.index is undefined
    console.log("deleting index ", index);
    let wasConfirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the attachment?");
    if(wasConfirmed) {

      this.thumbnailContainerRef.remove(index);

      return false;
    }
  }
```

`ThumbnailContext` is

```
export class ThumbnailContext{
  constructor(public divId:string,
              public imgId: string,
              public closeId:string,
              public imgSrc:string,
              public index:number,
              public viewRefId:EmbeddedViewRef<ThumbnailContext>){} 
}
```

I am unable to understand what the type of `context` is `let-context`=`thumbnailContext` is in the `ng-template`

Is `context` it

```
{
thumbnailContext:{divId:.., imgId:..}
}
```

or is `context`

```
{
divId:.., imgId:..,
}
```

In the `html` it looks like it is the latter one because I am able to assign the values in the html as `div id="{{context.divId}}`but when then I unable to do `context.index` in `deleteThumbnail`? Why I had to do `thumbnailContext.thumbnailContext.index`?

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding but it could be wrong so I am happy to accept other answers.

In templates, context information could be passed as an object and the passed object's key(s) will be available for binding by the local template `let` declarations.

eg, if the template is

```
<ng-template #myTemplate let-col let-foo="bar">
  <div>{{col}}</div>
  <div>{{foo}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

and if the object passed is `myContext = {$implicit: 'World', bar: 'Svet'};` then `col` will be assigned the value `World` because it is assigned the `$implicit` key's value and `foo` is assigned value of `bar` key i.e. `Svet`

In my example if I use `let-context="thumbnailContext"` in the html then I need `thumbnailContext` key in the context object.

```
 {thumbnailContext: new ThumbnailContext(divId, //storing information about this thumbnail in the context of teh embedded view
          imgId,
          closeId,
          imageString,this.thumbnailContainerRef.length,null)}
```

then `context` becomes `{divId:..., imgId:...}` and I can use it as `context.divId`

alternatively I could have used `let-context` only along with `$implicit`

```
 $implicit: new ThumbnailContext(...)
```

Now this is the part I am unsure of but the following is my understanding.Note that `context` variable in `let-context` is a key/value, not an object itself. In the example below
`<ng-template #eng let-name><span>Hello {{name}}!</span></ng-template>`, if the object passed is
   `myContext = {$implicit: 'World', localSk: 'Svet'};`
   then `name` is `World` (the value)

So when I pass `context` to `deleteThumbnail`, I am passing a key/value i.e. `thumbnail:{divId:..., imgId:...)`. Javascript wraps this   inside an object i.e.

```
   {
   thumbnailContext:{divId:..., imgId:...}
   }
```

thus to access it inside `deleteThumbnail`, I'll have to do `thumbnailContext.thumbnailContext.divId` because the 
   top level object (function argument) is called `thumbnailContext`